# What is the correct way to change permissions of the printer in /dev/usb/lp0?

Tags: usb, mount, printing

I use some commands to print text. However, when I connect my printer it becomes available under `/dev/usb/lp0`, which is owned by root and as a regular user I do not have access to this device.

What is the proper way of obtaining automated access? (automated in the sense that this permission should be automatically set when the printer is connected, and should not required typing a command manually every time it is connected).

Answer (score 1):

You don't fiddle with /dev/usb/lp0 - it is dynamically recreated on every startup or plugin.

Maybe you should, per sudo, add yourself to the group lpadmin.

I guess you're using CUPS for printing.

Open the webinterface

> http://localhost:631/admin

Since my userinterface of CUPS is localized for german users, I freely translate german expressions (back) to english. This might not produce exact fits.

Choose in the top-left group `printer` entry 3: `printer administration`. In the table `queue name` on the following page choose the printer (blue link). 
Next page: Choose `maintainance` `specify allowed users`.

The next step should be clear by itself.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not use CUPS for printing. I run something like `echo "Please print this" > /dev/usb/lp0`, so my application can directly print information. So I guess this would not apply, would it?

Comment: Afaik even this way involves CUPS. Is cups running? `ps -C cupsd` (note the trailing 'd' for 'daemon').

Comment: CUPS is running, but I was unable to fix the problem. In fact, other problems came up, related to a bigger issue. I have put it in a separate topic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74565/how-to-print-both-from-the-command-line-as-well-as-through-cups

Comment: And are you in group lpadmin? Did you inspect /var/log/cups/error.log?