# My printer in /dev/usb/lp0 always disappear after few seconds, and can't print, how to fix it? (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: drivers, usb, printing, udev

Please, help...

I have a 'EPPOS Model EPT-58H' thermal printer.
When I plugin via usb, it detected as `/dev/usb/lp0` with `ls -l /dev` command.
Then I run `echo "sometext" > /dev/usb/lp0` in terminal to check if my printer can actually print from my notebook, but nothing happened. The command itself seems succesfully executed, but my printer didn't print that `sometext`.

Then I tried to run `ls -l /dev/` again, my usb dissapear. It will show up again if I restart my printer.

Then I check with `dmesg` command, it shows that my printer didn't properly make connection with my notebook, it says ehci-pci error -32 or something like that.

I tried to install the driver from CUPS web on `localhost:631`, but I don't have any idea which one should works, you know, 'EPPOS' didn't even shown in the driver list.

Any idea how to solve this?
I've already search anywhere no clues about my printer issue.
Note, I did [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74565/how-to-print-both-from-the-command-line-as-well-as-through-cups) , and [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1436079&page=2) (and the link inside, except using wine solution, didn't even want to)

**Added Info 1**

Tried on 3 Laptop (2 Ubuntu 14.04, 1 Mac OS X), 1 PC with Ubuntu 14.04, 1 mini PC with Xubuntu. The result are all the same.

It only works with Windows (obviously, it has its driver for Windows), and a Laptop using FreeBSD.

It's almost 2 months now and didn't have solution for this.
Anyone?

Comment: Did you try to solve following [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems) article ?

Comment: @MicrosoftLinux something like that. But it's kind of unpopular thermal printer brand. After read those thread, I remember in the printer's manual guide (driver for windows), it is detected as virtual printer port in USB001. Not as Serial port, usb, or local port. And I don't see any about Virtual Printer Port in those article. Any thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give up trying this. It is not working either with 16.04 LTS which is using 4.4 linux kernel.

And on Windows 8.1 with proper driver ended with failed too.

Here I am finally using BSD (OpenBSD, NetBSD, and another BSD-based) succesfully working. On BSD, it is mounted as `ulpt0`.

It's a dead end trying on other Linux (Debian-based, Arch, RedHat, blabla).

So, at the end I use BSD to work this out.

Comment: So I guess it's `systemd`'s (the new init system that RedHat forced on *every* Linux distro) fault :(

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
echo "test print" | lpr
```

You can't simply echo to the device (well you can but it wont do anything).

Hope this helps!

Comment: it says " lpr: Error - no default destination available. " Then check again with `ls -l /dev/` my printer device disappear again. It will appear again everytime i restart my printer device. But always disappear after some half minutes i think. Is it driver, cups issue, or something about kernel? Do you have any idea? :(

Comment: Hmmm not exactly sure... was hoping the lpr would work...

Comment: @adadion have you looked into any drivers

Comment: it is clueless on Linux Driver. On the manual guide, it says support OPOS driver too. Then again, OPOS is windows based. I post this question on some site too, but it seems people don't have the answer. One weird thing I forgot to mention, whenever I plug my thermal printer, it detected as 2 thing, printer device, and storage device. Which is it don't have any storage device. It's weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try ro remove usb module:

```
sudo rmmod usblp
```